# Can the inequality $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2\sqrt{n} - 1$ be proved without induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Maybe some of you have seen one of the posts where the inequality $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2\sqrt{n}$ is proved by induction ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509840/use-induction-to-prove-that-1-frac-1-sqrt2-frac-1-sqrt3) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648907/induction-show-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-2-sqrtn-for-a?rq=1)). It can be proved without induction too, but the one with which I'm struggling to prove directly is this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2\sqrt{n} - 1 \qquad \text{For }n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq2.$$

By applying the telescoping property for sums I reached the same inequality with just the $2\sqrt{n}$, but I don't know how to deal with the $1$ there.

My attempt was this:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+ \sqrt{i}} &< \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+ \sqrt{i-1}} = \sqrt{i} -\sqrt{i-1}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} &< \sum_{i=1}^n[\sqrt{i} -\sqrt{i-1}]\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} &< \sqrt{n} -\sqrt{1-1}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} &< 2\sqrt{n}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Have you tried integration?

Comment: @TravisJ I don't know how to integrate (I haven't reached that part of the book yet (: ).

Comment: Have you tried $n=1$: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}=1\not<2\cdot\sqrt{1}-1$

Comment: @Pim Sorry. I had forgotten to include the constraints for $n$.

Comment: You mentioned you tried telescoping - showing your work would have helped.  Sometimes all it takes is to consider keeping one or two terms outside the telescoping part to get much better accuracy.

Comment: @Macavity Now I've put my attempt. I tried to start the summation with $k=2$ to end up with a $\sqrt{2}-1$ on the RHS, but that changed the LHS too.

Comment: @Jazz starting from $i=2$ is the only difference between your attempt and Daniels excellent answer below!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With telescoping, write

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}.$$

Then use

$$2(\sqrt{i} - \sqrt{i-1}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{i} + \sqrt{i-1}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$$

to conclude

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 1 + 2\sum_{i=2}^n (\sqrt{i} - \sqrt{i-1}) = 1 + 2(\sqrt{n}-1) = 2\sqrt{n} - 1.$$

Comment: That is slick... I like it.

Comment: That looks pretty neat (:.

Answer (score 3):

Using Abel summation formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula you have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{2t^{3/2}}dt$$
 where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor$
  is the integer part of $t.$
  So, if $n\geq2$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<\sqrt{n}+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{t}{2t^{3/2}}dt=2\sqrt{n}-1.$$

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do not understand that part with the integral |:, but I hope to do so soon (:.

Answer (score 0):

Please take this as a comment. By considering the convexity of $i\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$, you may use Jensen's inequality to find a **lower** bound for your sum:
$$
\sum_i\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}=n\sum_i\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\geq n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_ii/n}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{(n+1)/2}}\cdot
$$
This lower bound and the upper bound provided in the question look like this:
[image]

Because
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{(n+1)/2}}=\sqrt{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)/2}},
$$
you can use this lower bound to infer the divergence of the series.