# Let's prove this inequality, with/without induction $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1i \le \sqrt n$

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals, harmonic-numbers

Let's prove this inequality, using with induction (or without), for$\quad n\ge 7$ , $\quad \boxed{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac1i \le \sqrt n}$

My Attempt:

Since ;$\quad\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\dfrac1i=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac1i+\dfrac1{1+n}\le \sqrt n +\dfrac1{1+n}$

We need a prove this,
$$\sqrt n +\dfrac1{1+n}\le \sqrt{n+1}$$

Therefore,
$$\dfrac1{1+n}\le \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$$

Hence,
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}\le 1+n$$

So,
$$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\le 1+n$$

But, I couldn't complete this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint:**  $\dfrac{1}{i} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i-1}} = \sqrt{i} - \sqrt{i-1}, i \ge 4$.

Comment: Thank you  for good answer.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Another hint: harmonic series [is bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence) by $\ln{n}+1$, which is $\ln{n}+1 < \sqrt{n}$ at least because $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\log{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that ${1\over x}\le{1\over2\sqrt x}$ for $x\ge4$.  Combined with the standard integral comparison for the harmonic series, this lets us conclude that, for $n\ge7$

$$\begin{align}
1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+\cdots+{1\over n}
&\le1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over4}+{1\over5}+{1\over6}+{1\over7}+\int_7^n{dx\over x}\\
&={363\over140}+\int_7^n{dx\over x}\\
&\le{363\over140}+\int_7^n{dx\over2\sqrt x }\\
&={363\over140}+\sqrt n-\sqrt7\\
&\le\sqrt n\qquad\text{since }\left(363\over140\right)^2\approx6.7229\lt7
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you  for interesting:) :)

Answer (score 1):

For each $1\leq k\leq n$,

we have

$\frac{1}{k}\leq \int_{k-1}^k \frac{dt}{t}$

by addition, we get

$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}\leq \int_1^n\frac{dt}{t}=\log(n)$

and

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\leq 1+\log(n)$.

but

$x\mapsto 1+\log(x)-\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing at $[7,+\infty)$ by derivative.

so

$1+\log(x)\leq \sqrt{x}$.

qed.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say we want to use the known inequality<sup>1</sup> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2\sqrt k} \le \sqrt n.$$

Since for $k\ge 4$ we have $k\ge 2\sqrt k$ and $$\frac 1k \le \frac1{2\sqrt k},$$ it suffices to find $n_0\ge 4$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac 1k \le \sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac1{2\sqrt k}$$ and then we get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k = \sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac1k + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^n \frac1k \le  \sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac1{2\sqrt k} + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^n \frac1{2\sqrt k} = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2\sqrt k} \le \sqrt n.$$

Still the part which remains to be done manually is to find such $n_0$. [According to WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E10+1%2F%282*sqrt%28k%29%29+-+%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E10+1%2Fk) $n_0=10$ suffices.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are several posts on this site with proofs of this inequality, for example:

- [Use induction to prove that $ 1 + \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac {1}{\sqrt{3}} .... + \frac {1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2\sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509840/use-induction-to-prove-that-1-frac-1-sqrt2-frac-1-sqrt3)
- [Induction: show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < 2 \sqrt{n}$ for all n $\in Z_+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648907/induction-show-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-2-sqrtn-for-a)
- [Prove that $\sqrt{n} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \le 2 \sqrt{n} - 1$ is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ge 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880818/prove-that-sqrtn-le-sum-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-le-2-sqrtn-1-is)
- [Can the inequality $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2\sqrt{n} - 1$ be proved without induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156182/can-the-inequality-sum-limits-i-1n-frac1-sqrti-2-sqrtn-1-be-pr)

---

This is along the same lines as the hint posted [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983410/lets-prove-this-inequality-with-without-induction-sum-i-1n-frac1i-le-sq/1983427#1983427), just with more details.