# Show that $1998 < \sum_1^{10^6}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<1999$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Show that $1998 < \sum_1^{10^6}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<1999$ by first recalling the inequality:
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})$$ when $n=1, 2, 3...$

What I have tried to show using the inequality:

By the first step of induction to see if the inequality holds  :
$2(\sqrt{1+1}-\sqrt{1})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}<2(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{1-1})$ is true

Then by induction we have:

$2(\sqrt{n+1+1}-\sqrt{n+1})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+1-1})$

Then by using the fact that if $a>b$ and $c>0$ then $ac>bc$

The following should be true if the induction is right.

$\frac{2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}}>2(\sqrt{n+1+1}-\sqrt{n+1})$ by taking the square of both sides we have after expanding:
$$\frac{8n-8\sqrt{n^2+n}+4}{n+1}>8n+12-8\sqrt{n^2+3n+2}$$

Then placing everything onto one side:
$$\frac{-8n^2+8n\sqrt{n^2+3n+2}-12n+8\sqrt{n^2+3n+2}-8\sqrt{n^2+n}-8}{n+1}>0$$

Thouigh I'm not sure whether I'm going down the right direction. I had assumed that the LHS would cancel to provide something more exact. Any detailed hint son how to proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Estimating partial sums $\sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211973/estimating-partial-sums-sum-n-1m-frac1-sqrtn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need induction here. We have
$$n(n+1)=n^2+n<n^2+n+\frac14=\left(n+\frac12\right)^2$$
Take square roots:
$$\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}<n+\frac12$$
Multiply by $2/\sqrt n$ and rearrange:
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

Do the same with $n(n-1)$ to get the right-hand side of the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

More directly, multiply and divide by the conjugate:

$2 ( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} ) = 2 \frac{  ( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} )  ( \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} ) }{ ( \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} )} = \frac{2}{ ( \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} )} < \frac{2}{2\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n}}. $

Same for the RHS, can you complete it?