# P-integrability of unbounded function: 1/sqrt(x)

Tags: integration, measure-theory

This is question 10.2 in "Measures, Integrals and Martingales". The answer, which can be found [here](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions1-12.pdf) seems to contain a typo, and also I don't see why they pick such a complicated counterexample. I would like to know if the approach taken in the solutions would work, and also if my counterexample is sufficient.

The question:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a propability space. Find a counterexample to the claim: every P-integrable function $u \in \mathcal{L}^1$ is bounded. [Hint: you could try to take $\Omega = (0,1)$, $P = \lambda^1$, and show that $u = 1/\sqrt{x}$ is Lebesgue integrable on (0,1) by finding a sequence of suitable simple functions that is above u on, say, $(1/m,1)$, and then let $m \to \infty$ using Beppo Levi]

Now in the solutions, they use $u(\frac{j+1}{n}) = \sqrt\frac{j+1}{n}$, which should be the inverse and thus the following convergence argument doesn't apply.

But apart from that, why not just take an atom A (set with no subsets in the $\sigma$-algebra), construct a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(A) = 1$, $\mu(A^c) = 0$ and set $u$ to 1 on $A$ and to infinity on $A^c$? That would be sufficient to falsify the claim right?

Comment: Yes, if $u(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ then $u((j+1)/n)=\sqrt{n/(j+1)}$. Does this rather typo deserve a question? Re why not the example you suggest, please note that both yours and the text example are interesting. Pointing out that the problem is *not* only with measures having atoms is necessary, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you! the typo on itself is not so interesting, but because of the typo I cannot check if their answer is correct - and also if my answer is lacking. Which is why I posted a question

Comment: If your question is how to complete Exercise 10.2's solution, note that one is left with $$\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{j+1}}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \int_1^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left.2\sqrt{x}\right|_1^n<2.$$

Comment: ...or see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/648907/) or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1211973/) for an elementary proof. (... and I'll fix the typo.)